# CGFloat substraction problem

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
_screen.brightness = _screen.brightness - 0.1;
```

This line of code gives me an unexpected result.
When I call the `NSLog(@"%.2f", _screen.brightness - 0.1);` command, then it prints the
`-0.00` value. When I test to this `if (_screen.brightness == 0)`, it gives me `NO`.
Why this happens? Is there any conversion problem?

Here's my accessor methods in the class of `_screen`'s object:

```
- (CGFloat)brightness {
    return 1 - _dimmingView.alpha;
}

- (void)setBrightness:(CGFloat)brightness {
    if (brightness < self.minValue || brightness > self.maxValue) {
        return;
    }
    _dimmingView.alpha = 1 - brightness;
}
```

Comment: How is it possible that you've graduated to programming an iPhone, yet never learned about the imprecision of floating point?  Methinks you perhaps skipped a few chapters in the textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic doesn't necessarily give you the precise answers you're looking for. Better men than I have explained it here: [C# float bug? 0.1 - 0.1 = 1.490116E-08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478474/c-float-bug-0-1-0-1-1-490116e-08). For a different language but the point remains the same.

Comment: ... and to solve the exact problem posted, you might consider using `fabsf(_screen.brightness) < 0.05` as a test for "equal to zero" given that you're going down in steps of 0.1.

Comment: I am going to try these out. Thanks guys!